# Create customer address using magento soap API in android

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-address, soap-api-v2

I am able to create a customer using customerCustomerCreate api, and getting the customer id. Now my requirement is to create the address of the customer, for that i am calling the customerAddressCreate api. but somehow i am not able to create the customer address. I tried with the code below:

```
try {

                SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                env.dotNet = false;
                env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
                env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");

                request.addProperty("username", "user");
                request.addProperty("apiKey", "apikey");

                env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
                Object result = env.getResponse();

                Log.e("sessionId", result.toString());




                String sessionId = result.toString();


   request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerAddressCreate");
            request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);

            request.addProperty("customerId",custId);

            SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerAddressEntityCreate");

            customerEntity.addProperty("city", "bangalore");
            customerEntity.addProperty("company", "outthinking");
            customerEntity.addProperty("country_id", "01");
            customerEntity.addProperty("fax", "08012345");
            customerEntity.addProperty("firstname", "amit");
            customerEntity.addProperty("lastname", "chandra");
            customerEntity.addProperty("middlename", "raj");
            customerEntity.addProperty("postcode", "560007");
            customerEntity.addProperty("prefix", "a");
            customerEntity.addProperty("region_id", 03);
            customerEntity.addProperty("region", "karnataka");
            customerEntity.addProperty("street",Arrays.toString(myStrings));
            customerEntity.addProperty("suffix", "ac");
            customerEntity.addProperty("telephone", "+91-9962025341");
            customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_billing", false);
            customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_shipping", false);

            request.addProperty("addressdata", customerEntity);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

where myStrings is array of string of street. But i am getting the following error:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: '100' faultstring: 'Please enter the first name.
Please enter the last name.
Please enter the street.
Please enter the city.
Please enter the telephone number.
Please enter the zip/postal code.
Please enter the country.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code and please provide any solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. If anybody still facing the problem then try this:

```
 request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerAddressCreate");
                    request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
                    //int customerId = Integer.parseInt(custId);
                    request.addProperty("customerId","custId");

                    SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,              "customerAddressEntityCreate");

                    customerEntity.addProperty("city", "city");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("company","");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("country_id", "IN");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("fax", "");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("firstname", fname);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("lastname", lName);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("middlename", "");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("postcode", zipCode);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("prefix", "");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("region_id",1);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("region", region);

                    SoapObject streetEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "street");


                    streetEntity.addProperty("street", street1);
                    //streetEntity.addProperty("street", street2);

                    customerEntity.addProperty("street",streetEntity);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("suffix", "");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("telephone", "8147555522");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_billing", true);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_shipping", false);

                    request.addProperty("addressData", customerEntity);



                    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
                    result = env.getResponse();
```

It's working fine for me. All you have to do is just change the name "addressdata" as addressData.